# ASP.NET 4.0 using Ajax with existing DropDownList control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-controls

I need to have an update occur on the backend every time the user changes a value in a ASP.NET DropDownList control.  I want to do this using AJAX so the browser does not do a total refresh and reposition the user off of the control they are currently on.  My issue is that the user is performing a lot on input on this one page so I want to auto save with each change.  I am running into issues where the Session State is timing out and the user loses all their changes.  I tried changing the timeout setting in the web.config but that didn't work.  Therefore, I want to make an AJAX callback as each DropDownList control is changed.  How would that be done?  I am not currently using Ajax anywhere in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your DropDownList inside an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx).